# Piip piip piip, new X220 Broken After 1 Week Usage? How can I debug this machine?

Tags: windows, thinkpad

I bought new x220 laptops and now I got the first one apparently broken. I tried to install F-Secure some virus protection, I left it on the installtion for some hours and now the machine won't start. It makes 3 short piips when it tries to boots up. When I tried to install F-secure, it tried to remove the default 2009 Norton Anti-virus software. I have no interest to debug this issue -- I would appreciate some help about what to do, I have some XYZ support from Lenovo but I have no idea whether it covers this kind of things. It is apparently something messed up with the OS Windows 7 Professional, any idea how to debug Windows box?

The F-secure software, all these Norton and Windows XYZ stuff are genuine stuff. When I press the start-up button, it closes down immediately. Now not even making any loud -- how can I get this machine alive -- even to get into the BIOS or to get the bootloader read when it does not boot?

Btw. The battery led makes 3 short blinking and then pause, in morse, ...---...---.

Comment: 3 beeps at boot = hardware issue. It definately should be covered by the warranty.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: any idea whether they can come up to fetch this dxmn laptop -- this is darn stupid time just in the middle of development. Some courier perhaps? Well, it is night here -- have to get into some lenovo support, I hate this -- it smells actually bad -- like something burnt.

Comment: Yes, this box is dead. The only led that now blinks is the finger-print -led. I wish I could fix it myself...

Comment: depends on where you are. It should be pretty fast though, since its a clear case of something that is covered under the warranty

Comment: burnt? Thats.. NOT in any way normal. At this point, no, you certainly cannot fix it yourself.

Comment: **HINT** Contact directly to the IBM service (not any 3rd party service)! I got the support in one day from IBM but the third-party service did not get the parts even in four days. I am now trying to move the fresh W7 os to my server [here](http://superuser.com/questions/397646/windows-7-filesystem-and-backuping-it-in-ix). For future random walkers, remember to clone the machine straight away so you have a backup media for this kind of burns, had to learn it the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user manual indicates that [it is a memory error](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/x220_x220i_x220tablet_x220itablet_ug_en.pdf) - see page 212. It should be covered under warranty, and since its the inner ram bank, i don't recommend trying to reseat it yourself.

Comment: Thank you, it is precisely that problem. Contacted Lenovo, 2AM -- well still 46 hours +8hors to wait at least, irritating.